# Installing SwingX in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-6.9, swingx

I have problem installing SwingX in my Netbeans IDE. I want to play with JXPanel and related components but i could not get right library and get it going.

I tried to download swingx.jar but there is no valid link available in internet. I somehow managed to download swingx-1.6.jar, swingx-beaninfo-0.9.7 and swingbean.jar. I imported these jar files into the new library i created "SwingX" using tools->library and after that went to tools->palette->Swing/AWT Components and added a new palette group called SwingX and added the created library (SwingX) into it. Now i get a block in my IDE as shown in the figure.

**Picture 1**
[image: Picture 1]

Then i added the library into my project  which is shown in the **picture 2** and when i tried to insert JXXollapsiblePane from the pallete group into a JFrame i am gettign the following error shown in **picture3**.

**Picture 2**
[image: Picture 3]

**Picture 3**
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Sigh ... the downloads are completely screwed on java.net migration - but they are there: go to the download area and follow the instructions in the _description_ (not the content) of the txt file download-broken. Sorry for the mess, it's beyond our control. As to Netbeans, can't say much (not exactly a fan of NetBeans ;-) - just: be sure to use the same versions. a beaninfo of version 0.9.7 is bound to make problems when used with swingx1.6 (BTW: the most recent release is 1.6.2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add **swingx-1.6.jar** to your project instead of swingx-beaninfo-0.9.7