# Java Swing table tree

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtreetable

When you open a XML in Eclipse, the content can be shown in as a tree structure like

[image: XML tree view]

The tree is "embedded" in a table and the content is showed in a seperate column.

This would be very nice to replicate in Swing, not for XML content specifically, but for similar data with tree structure.

**UPDATE**

I just learned about JTreeTable, but I really need to do this in *NetNeans*. Should probably have mentioned that, sorry.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "do it in Netbeans"? Do you need to use the component in a GUI designer?

Comment: @lhballoti - Yes, It's for work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/) has a JXTreeTable, it's based on but much improved over the oldish examples (links to sun code/article) cited by @mKorbel

Comment: @kleopatra - For NetBeans, i'm not so sure, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612782/installing-swingx-in-netbeans

Comment: @Theodor: repeating myself (the comment I made there) - mixing a beaninfo 0.9.7 with a swingx of 1.6 is _certain_ to pose problems ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra - After some head scratching, JXTreeTable works beautiful. Sorry that I doubted you =) Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Check the following:

- [TreeTable](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/)
- This [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/JTreeTablecomponent.htm)
- Code depots by [Swing Guru](http://aephyr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/)
- Netbeans IDE's [Outline](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/swing_outline_component)
- Something more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110/file-browser-gui/6182305#6182305)
- [Commercial products](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You could try subclassing JTable and making your own [custom renderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) with behavior that adds/removes new rows when you expand/collapse a node.

Comment: -1 - you tried it? Very unlikely to get anything half-way robust by on-the-fly custom renderers, there's more issues to solve than mere visuals. Though, at it's very base, the typical J/X/TreeTable implementations _do_ have a custom renderer for the hierarchical column :-)

Comment: +1 I do it this way already, vary fast for large data sets. The renderer has to render the indentation and the collapse/expand icon, too.