# JTree without leaf

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode

Is it possible to make a JTree without leaf?  If it is possible then please tell me way.

[image: JTree image]

I want to convert these highlighted leafs as the folder or parent.

If you want any thing else apart from it then please let me know.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking do you mean you want your leaf nodes to be represented in the UI as folders?

Comment: did you read [JTree tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html), to create only XxxTreeNodes

Comment: @mkorbel I have already read this tutorial sir,I did not get my answer over  there that's why i put a question here.

Comment: to create only Nodes, but doesn't make me sence, Iwoundn't be going this way, better would be customize JTrees look, put there Icons that change built_in output to the screen, the same for nodes, same for leafs

Comment: @mKorbel i.e we can't make a jtree without leaf.is it?

Comment: you can to create only nodes without leafs

Comment: @mkorble yes,I want that only.Could you please help me out.

Comment: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8843638/714968)

Answer (score 2):

As shown in this [`FileTreeModel`](http://java.dzone.com/news/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-), `isLeaf()` should return `false` and `getChildCount()` should return `0` for directories. The result is illustrated [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692); although not apparent,  the `test` directory is empty.

```
@Override
public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
    File f = (File) node;
    return !f.isDirectory();
}

@Override
public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
    File f = (File) parent;
    if (!f.isDirectory()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return f.list().length;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think if you always return true from isLeaf in your TreeModel but return 0 from getChildCount for your leaf nodes you'll get what you want.

Comment: Thanks Tom for your reply But i want to know how to restrict tree to nodes only.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand what you're asking, re-reading seems to point this as the answer especially given your reply to my comment.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer more.