# Enable scrolling inside a JTree's node

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jtree

I'm trying to build a debug GUI listing errors while categorizing them for a better overview. Therefore I am building a `JTree` with `JTables` as leaves. Since the tables need some space a `JScrollPane` is required. Now displaying this works more or less, but I can't scroll inside the table.

`CellRenderer`:

```
private static class MyTableCellRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded,
            boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        Object v = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
        if (v instanceof JTable) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(((JTable) v).getTableHeader());
            panel.add(new JScrollPane((JTable) v));
            return panel;
        }
        return new JLabel(v.toString());
    }
}
```

Panel & tree:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.add(panel);

DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
JTree tree = new JTree(parentNode);
tree.setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
DefaultMutableTreeNode tableNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new JTable(new Object[0][], new Object[] {"col1"}));
//add some content
parentNode.add(tableNode);
```

Any suggestions on how to scroll inside the table?

Comment: [for example ???](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843638/put-jtable-in-the-jtree)

Comment: Saw this (or a reference for it) earlier, but it didn't work. And as I said. Displaying the table works, only scrolling/resizing columns doesn't.