# How to present a hierarchical String list with checkboxes in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jtreetable

So. The ideas have been a few.. no good ones.. So here is the problem i have incountered and can not figure out a solution for.

I need to have a txt file containing a hierarchical list of things to do, looking something like this:

- Ask a question

  - Before question asked, check similar questions
  - Formulate the question so that the problem is clearly shown.
- Post the question

  - Hold your thumbs that this might save your day.

The txt file should in the program fill a list shown in a JPanel and after each step have a checkbox to comfirm "I have been a good boy and done this". 
The list can change over time and grow and shrink, so the solution needs a scrollbar.
The list should also contaion a capability to show more the one row.

The solution im working on is done in Jave compiler 1.6 and im using Swing for my layout.
Ideas i have had so far are: 
Modified JTable... and the other solutions i am asshamed of..
And thats about it.. ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JTree` with custom renderer. The renderer should be a panle with checkbox and text area.

Answer (score 2):

- have look at [JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)
- have to override [JTree Renderer and Editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) (comcept is similair for `JTable` and `JTree`)
- all data are stored in the `DefaultTreeModel`
- examples about [Tree Model,Tree Renderer Editor, Tree](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm) and [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.tree/pkg.html)

Comment: Wish i could upvote, cause this awnser helpt me alot too! Tho the solution was in the other awnser the way there was throw yours!

Answer (score 2):

Also consider `org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`, discussed [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692) and illustrated below. It's not apparent in the screenshot, but the the `Outline` instance has been added to a `JScrollPane`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would say JTreeTable is a right choice. It will provide a lot of power and flexibility. Please see some very basic examples:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things14/index.html
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/JTreeTablecomponent.htm

For any serious purpose please use a mature implementation provided, for example, by a SwingLab project:

- http://swingx.java.net/
- http://java.net/projects/swinglabs

Please also see the following answer:

- [Java Swing table tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122901/java-swing-table-tree)

Comment: shaking head on these outdated references: they are the very first attempt (more a case study than usable) with tons of problems which are fixed (not all though, though) in JXTreeTable ...

Comment: I'm suggesting an idea, but not the actual implementation.