# Java Swing: Tree-Table widget except for SwingX's JXTreeTable?

Tags: java, swing, gtk, swingx, jxtreetable

I look for a **pure Swing** JXTreeTable equivalent.

**Why I don't want to use SwingX's JXTreeTable:**

When I use `SwingX's JXTreeTable` in Linux with Swing's `GTK+` LookAndFeel, it crashes!

It crashes with this message: `"GThread-ERROR **: GThread system may only be initialized once.
aborting..."` (It's even not a "catchable" exception, just an immediate crash on JXTreeTable instantiation)

As my GUI works well with other LookAndFeels and as before adding the JXTreeTable, my GUI worked well with `GTK+` LookAndFeel, **I conclude that SwingX's JXTreeTable itself uses GTK+/GLib and thus causing the crash.**

So can anyone help me? Does anyone have a **pure Swing** implementation of JXTreeTable equivalent widget?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Swing table tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122901/java-swing-table-tree)

Comment: In the reference you wrote, they suggest to use SwingX. I look for the opposite

Comment: That link contain suggestions and examples in pure swing of `JTreeTable`.

Comment: _I conclude that SwingX's JXTreeTable itself uses GTK+/GLib_ no, it doesn't and it **is** a _pure Swing implementation_ (whatever that means ;-), no external dependencies on anything. Finding the root problem would involve some digging (not me, not having access to a Linus/GTK system) that you could help with showing a SSCCE so that somebody might reproduce the error.